# How to find data source for a SharePoint 2007 Access Web Datasheet

Tags: 2007, view, datasheet, access, web

I inherited a SharePoint 2007 site.  There is a Access Web datasheet that is retrieving data from some kind of data source.  The user has informed me that it is no longer updating.  For further troubleshooting I am trying to find the data source, and none of the users do not no what it is.  How do go about finding out what data source is being used?  The datasheet itself does not give any errors when attempting to retrieve data.